# Dúvida com inserção de dados WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estou usando o Postman:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Erro: "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Tenho o Código do Controller:

```html
//http://localhost:1608/api/ApiGuiaCidade/cadastrar/cliente
        //"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("cadastrar/cliente/")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostCadastro(Cliente cliente)
        {
            try
            {
                var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
                tCliente.Inseri(cliente);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Cadastro do cliente" + cliente.Nome + "realizado.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Tenho da aplicação:

```html
        public void Inseri(Cliente cliente)
        {
            var strQuery = "";
            strQuery += "INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO,EMAIL, SENHA)";
            strQuery += string.Format(" VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}' )", cliente.Nome, cliente.DataNascimento, cliente.Email, cliente.senha);

            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                contexto.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Como você tá disparando o *payload* pelo Postman? Pode tirar uma foto da tela?

Comment: Por que você põe o realce de sintaxe como **html**?

Comment: Eu conseguir fazer a edição adicionando foto, mais o erro agora é:

Could not get any response
This seems to be like an error connecting to http://localhost:1608/api/ApiGuiaCidade/cadastrar/cliente. The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.

Answer (score 3):

Veja, o erro diz (ênfase minha)

> The request entity's media type **'text/plain'** is not supported for this resource.

Na hora de fazer o `POST` pelo **postman** você precisa mudar o **content type** para **application/json**

Comment: Fiz a alteração, agora tenho o erro:
Could not get any response
This seems to be like an error connecting to http://localhost:1608/api/ApiGuiaCidade/cadastrar/cliente. The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.